# MongoDB returns not existing documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm starting with *MongoDB* and *NodeJS* (*Mongoose* lib) and spotted strange issues.

I have a query as follows:

```
StationCurrentState.find({ stationId: { $in: stationIdsList } })
```

which works fine, but somehow it always contains extra not existing documents with not existing `ObjectIDs`.

```
[
{
    "_id": "617a729439db114344f2f054",
    "stationId": "152160050",
    "__v": 0,
    "currentDischarge": 59.5,
    "currentLevel": 167,
    "date": "2021-11-17T07:15:22.442Z",
    "trend": "const"
},
{
    "_id": "617ad914c190e83e9b602d96",
    "stationId": "152160050",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "617ad9f898fd3f60ac390d32",
    "stationId": "152160050",
    "__v": 0
},
```

....
]

If I would extend list of input to 2 ids, than:

```
[
{
    "_id": "617a729439db114344f2ef36",
    "stationId": "153140200",
    "__v": 0,
    "currentDischarge": null,
    "currentLevel": 57,
    "date": "2021-11-17T07:15:32.892Z",
    "trend": "const"
},
{
    "_id": "617a729439db114344f2f054",
    "stationId": "152160050",
    "__v": 0,
    "currentDischarge": 59.5,
    "currentLevel": 167,
    "date": "2021-11-17T07:15:22.442Z",
    "trend": "const"
},
{
    "_id": "617ad914c190e83e9b602c78",
    "stationId": "153140200",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "617ad914c190e83e9b602d96",
    "stationId": "152160050",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "617ad9f898fd3f60ac390d32",
    "stationId": "152160050",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "617ad9f898fd3f60ac390c14",
    "stationId": "153140200",
    "__v": 0
}
```

As can be seen given stationId is interlapping on those dummy results. Only first 2 are real data in database

To workaround this I had to add a limit equal to length of `stationIdsList`, but this is not the right solution.

Similar thing when I tried aggregate on *MongoDB Atlas* (Cloud).

First I used match to find only one object, then lookup:

```
"{
  from: 'stationcurrentstates',
  localField: 'stationId',
  foreignField: 'stationId',
  as: 'state'
}"
```

So I have state field which is an array but in reality only the first object is real one (containing all data). The other objects have somehow matching `stationId` field but they do not exist (no other data visible but `ObjectId` probably generated).

What am I missing about *MongoDB* schema, that generates such behavior? My schemas are very simple, I'm sure that data is not duplicated.

Comment: The [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) query operator only selects documents if matches the values in the specified array. This is same as using the `$or` query operator  - the `$in` is convenient for specifying a number of values.

Comment: @prasad_ so? I know what this operator is doing. This is logical way, but why it is returning not existing objects putting into them just field which I'm looking for, nothing else. It is like - I have list of 2 ids, so I should receive 2 objects matched with this ids (assuming they are unique), not 10 objects, where first 2 are valid, other ones who knows

Comment: You can attach some sample documents, the actual query you had tried on them and the result you are troubled with - it will be easy to understand. It can help make any useful suggestions.

Comment: Ok, I hvae updated question with it